# Получить данные из SQL в код c#

Tags: c#, sql

Я новичек в програмировании, не до конца понимаю методы классы и обьекты. Мне нужно: Подключитесь к локальному SQL-серверу с помощью C # и загрузите все экземпляры данных в три таблицы. Надо загрузить все переменные из каждой таблицы и создать объекты Accomodation. Нужно Ввести каждый тип объекта в списке в соответствующий класс City; Другими словами, каждый список в каждом обьекте должен быть заполнен тем же количеством данных, что и в базе данных SQL! Как это правильно сделать? Написала часть кода(классы) но застряла и не знаю как с ппомощью метода получить данные`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient; //

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            City Amsterdam = new City("null", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); // object
            City Boston = new City("null", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); // object
            City Barcelona = new City("null", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); // object

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-OBD0K6JL;Initial Catalog=airbnbtest;Integrated Security=True";

            try

            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand myQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Boston2;", conn); //same name as in Boston2 i SQL
                SqlDataReader myReader = myQuery.ExecuteReader();

                SqlCommand myQuery2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Barcelona2;", conn); //same name as in Boston2 i SQL
                SqlDataReader myReader2 = myQuery.ExecuteReader();

                List<string> avtoNames = new List<string>();
                int host_id;
                string room_type;
                int reviews; //same name as in SQL 
                while (myReader.Read())

                {

                    string variabel1 = myReader["bedrooms"].ToString();
                    reviews = (int)myReader["reviews"];
                    host_id = (int)myReader["host_id"];
                    room_type = (string)myReader["room_type"];
                    Console.WriteLine("Revieews:" + reviews+"," + "Host ID:"+ host_id+ "," +
                        "Room type:"+ " "+ room_type);
                    Console.ReadLine();


                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
        //method 

        static City GetCityData (string sqlcity)
        {
            City stad = new City("Name", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            stad.Population = 0;
            stad.AvgIncome = 0;
            stad.NumTourists = 0;
            stad.AntalAccommondations = 0;


            return stad; 

        }
}


}`
```

Comment: **(1)** в конструкторе класса `City` 5 числовых полей, а присваиваете вы только 4 почему-то; используйте конструктор с параметрами по прямому назначению -- сразу после создания им экземпляра незачем снова перезадавать(=0) значения полей этого экземпляра; **(2)** *>> не знаю как с помощью метода получить данные* -- что делается в цикле `while (myReader.Read()) {  }`?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте EntityFramework или Dapper(более легковесна и быстрее). Эти ORM сами переведут выбранные значение в классы. Ну и конечно почитайте про ORM в целом

Answer (score 0):

Судя по вашему коду, у вас должна быть модель класса, примерно выглядящая так:

```
class City
{
    public string Bedrooms { get; set; }
    public int Reviews { get; set; }
    public int HostId { get; set; }
    public string RoomType { get; set; }
}
```

Можно добавить конструкторы по необходимости.

Код чтения из БД, заполняющий коллекций классов `City`:

```
List<City> cities = new List<City>();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-OBD0K6JL;Initial Catalog=airbnbtest;Integrated Security=True";
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand myQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Boston2;", conn))
    using (SqlDataReader myReader = myQuery.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            var city = new City();

            city.Bedrooms = myReader["bedrooms"].ToString();
            city.Reviews = (int)myReader["reviews"];
            city.HostId = (int)myReader["host_id"];
            city.RoomType = (string)myReader["room_type"];

            cities.Add(city);
        }
    }

    using (SqlCommand myQuery2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Barcelona2;", conn))
    using (SqlDataReader myReader = myQuery2.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // аналогичный код
    }
}
```

Если хотите получить более точные ответы, приведите структуру своих таблиц в БД и классы `City` и `Accomodation`, который вы упомянули в вопросе.